# Best order to finish the game

Tags: arrays

- A game has multiple stops and the stops are ordered.
- A player has to go through all the stops one by one to finish the game.
- Every time player enters a stop he gains some energy, when he leaves he loses some energy.
- At any point if energy level falls to zero or below, player dies.

Write a program/logic such that player goes through all the stops.

By ordered I mean, if stops are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, Player can start at any point but has to go to next point after leaving and in clockwise matter. So only possible orders here are, 12345, 23451, 34512, 45123,51234.

Example,

- Stops 1 2 3 4 5
- Gain  1 2 3 4 5
- Loss  3 4 5 1 2

Comment: Looks like DP problem to me

Comment: I need to maintain the order so wondering how exactly to go about this.